# SwiftUI - Apple Watch Menu (Force Touch)

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a menu on Apple Watch using SwiftUI but I can't find a way to do it. Even on the `interface.storyboard`, I can't drag/drop the menu.

Did you manage to make it work with SwiftUI? If yes, how?

I searched online but nothing so far.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It's important to remember that unlike on iOS, a view can have only one single context menu, individual elements within the view can not have their own context menu.

Anyway, to implement a context menu (force touch menu) on Apple Watch with SwiftUI, add the `.contextMenu()` modifier to top-most view in your `body`

Example:

```
var body: some View {
    Group {
        Text("Hello Daymo")
    }
    .contextMenu(menuItems: {
        Button(action: {
            print("Refresh")
        }, label: {
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("Refresh view")
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Edit the button (or add buttons) as you see fit.

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: 'contextMenu(menuItems:)' was deprecated in watchOS 7.0

Comment: Any other option for watchos 7?